# Ubuntu 12.10 sources.list empty after install

Tags: apt-get, ubuntu-12.10

I recently installed the Ubuntu 12.10 server version from a USB flash drive. The step "Install additional software" or whatever kept on failing, so I ignored it and continued. Everything else worked like a charm.

I thought.

It turns out, the only two entries in my sources.list are the install CD. This means that I have no way of getting anything installed.

Can someone give me a short list of repositories that I need so I can add them to the sources.list file? And on a similar note: What is the comment character for the sources list? #?

Comment: yes, '#' comments lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a neat little sources generator:
http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

But why on earth did it happen? We will never know.

Comment: yep, that website/tool is an arse-saver. i used it in the past several times.